# How to start NumberPicker from beginning (index 0) when an event is triggered?
(Like click event or something)

Tags: android

I have two NumberPickers, the first one is 'date slot' (npDate) and second one is 'time slot' (npTime). When user selects Date slot from npDate the other NumberPicker npTime should start from beginning (index 0) reloading npTime with new values as per date slot selected. What is happening right now is, npTime is changing values as per date slot but it is not rolling back to the index 0.
How could I get the other NumberPicker to roll back to index 0?

Answer (score 0):

Use the setOnValueChangedListener method  from the numberpick. In this method, set index Zero to other Picker. Hope I help a little.